# Sidekiq Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using *sidekiq* in my Rails App to asynchronously execute a stored procedure in my *SQL Server* database when the user moves from one specific page to another.

The problem is that the stored procedure takes up to 4 minutes to complete and *sidekiq* returns a timeout message (and then retry).

I don't want to change my application's global database timeout setting in *database.yml* (I don't even know if it would resolve, but I can't do that).

Is there any way to tell *sidekiq* that my method can take long and then stop getting timeout errors?

I really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE #1**

2013-06-03T17:14:18Z 6136 TID-1ac4ik GeneratePropertyProfile JID-de571df94f21b9159c74db6b INFO: start

2013-06-03T17:19:03Z 6136 TID-1ac4ik GeneratePropertyProfile JID-de571df94f21b9159c74db6b INFO: fail: 285.218 sec

2013-06-03T17:19:03Z 6136 TID-1ac4ik WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"GeneratePropertyProfile", "args"=>[{"id"=>41915658}], "jid"=>"de571df94f21b9159c74db6b", "error_message"=>"TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out: EXEC gaiainc.sp_wait", "error_class"=>"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid", "failed_at"=>2013-06-03 17:19:03 UTC, "retry_count"=>0}

2013-06-03T17:19:03Z 6136 TID-1ac4ik WARN: TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out: EXEC gaiainc.sp_wait

**UPDATE #2**

I got it to work without changing my *database.yml*. However, I had to add the following code in my initializers/sidekiq.rb:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['timeout'] = 300000
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I know it's an ugly solution but I had no time to find another solution to make it work.
If anyone has a cleaner solution, please reply to this topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

TERM signals that Sidekiq should shut down within the -t timeout option. Any workers that do not finish within the timeout are forcefully terminated and their messages are lost. The timeout [defaults](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#overview) to 25 seconds

The Sidekiq TERM timeout is set in config/sidekiq.yml or with the -t parameter. Sidekiq will do its best to exit by this timeout when it receives TERM.

```
:timeout: 300
```

Comment: I tried to put the timeout setting in config/sidekiq.yml, but the problem persists. I set timeout to 300 and called a stored procedure with a sleep of 285s and sidekiq keep throwing me timeout errors.

Comment: Check my last post update: that's the output from sidekiq. In 285s my stored procedure (and consequently my _perform_ method) finished, but sidekiq says that the method failed.

Comment: The problem is the database adapter timeout, and not sidekiq. I got it to work changing the databse timeout settings in database.yml, however I can't change my production database timeout setting to 300000ms. Any idea?

Comment: well, if it's impossible to change database parameters, i recommend you to check whether its possible to simplify or optimise database requests. Maybe you are doing some updates for huge collection for each item, which can be replaced with update with join, or inserting lots of items by one, and they can be inserted with only one request. Need more info...

Comment: I can optimize my database request (not much), but unfortunately I have no time to do it now. I used an ugly (I think) solution to make it work - check my post update.